# Angular 4 - Using Asynchronous custom validators

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<div [class]="new_workflow_row_class" id="new_workflow_row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="checkmark-container" i18n>New Workflow
            <input type="checkbox" id="new-workflow" name="new-workflow" [(ngModel)]="new_checkbox" (click)="uncheckBox($event, 'edit')"> 
            <span class="checkmark" id="new-workflow-checkmark" [class]="checkmark_class"><span id="new-workflow-checkmark-content"></span>{{checkmark_content}}</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" *ngIf="new_checkbox" id="new_workflow_name" name="new_workflow_name" (keyup)="clearWorkflowError(true)" [(ngModel)]="new_workflow" placeholder="Enter Workflow Name">
        <p [hidden]="!show_workflow_error && !workflowForm.errors" class="workflow-error" i18n>The workflow name already exists. Please use a different name.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component.ts:

```
duplicateWorkflowValidator(control: FormControl) {
    console.log("this validator was called!");
    clearTimeout(this.workflowTimeout);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (this.new_workflow != '') {
            this.workflowTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                this
                    .requestService
                    .findWorkflow(control.value)
                    .subscribe((results: any) => {
                        let data: any = results.data;

                        if (data.duplicate) {
                            resolve({ duplicateWorkflow: { value: control.value}})
                        }
                        else if (results.status == "OK") {
                            resolve(null);
                        }
                    })
                ;
            }, 500);
        }
        else {
            resolve(null);
        }


    })

}
```

Inside constructor for component.ts:

```
this.workflowForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(this.new_workflow, [
        Validators.required,
    ], this.duplicateWorkflowValidator.bind(this))
});
```

I am trying to bind this asynchronous validator to the reactive form but it's not working. I want to use the duplicateWorkflowValidator inside workflowForm and have it trigger an error message when it finds a duplicate workflow.

How do I a) bind the validator to the reactive form properly, b) access the validator errors? Thanks in advance, hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Do you get any error?

Comment: yes, the validation errors are giving me the "required" error even when the field is not empty.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `debugger;` before the `if` and step through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing template forms with reactive forms. Chose one approach. In the below example I am using reactive forms.

Try this simplified version. For demonstration purposes below the validator will fail when I type `test`, but succeed when I type anything else. You will need to change that to your service call.

https://angular-sjqjwh.stackblitz.io

**Template:**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" formControlName="name">
            <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.name.hasError('duplicateWorkflow')">
                Workflow already exists!
            </div>
            {{ myForm.controls.name.hasError('duplicateWorkflow') | json }}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, Form, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  workflowTimeout: number = 0;
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl('', 
        [Validators.required], 
        this.duplicateWorkflowValidator.bind(this))
    });
  }

  duplicateWorkflowValidator(control: FormControl) {
    console.log("this validator was called!");

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (control.value === 'test') {
        this.workflowTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
          resolve({ duplicateWorkflow: { value: control.value } })
        }, 500);
      }
      else {
        resolve(null);
      }
    });
  }
}
```